# Transform a matrix 18x6692 to a matrix 1x120450 matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

i have a char matrix (in matlab) 18x6692 and i want this to be a matrix with 1 row and 6692x18=120450 column.
I'm not able to do this, can you help me?
I also tried with a smaller matrix: from 2x4 to 1x8 with no results.
thank you

Comment: Could you please post some of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the [**colon operator**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and transpose the vector:

```
A = A(:).'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function:

```
B = reshape(A,1,[]);
```

where `A` is the input matrix, `1` is the number of rows and `[]` is to indicate that the number of columns is to be calculated from the number of elements in `A`.

Note that this stacks all columns of `A`. If you want to concatenate along the rows, you can do this by transposing `A` first

```
B = reshape(A.',1,[]);
```